# I want to add a button in my game using swift

Tags: swift, button, skspritenode

So in my code I want to add an SKSpriteNode that I can use as a button to transition onto another scene, so could you possibly show me how I do that without using gameScene.sks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you need to create a sub-node first

```
override init(size: CGSize){

    let playButton = SKLabelNode()
    playButton.fontSize = 40
    playButton.text = NA_MENU_BTN_PLAY
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 300)
    //give it an unique name
    playButton.name = "Play"
    playButton.zPosition = 3
    addChild(playButton)

}
```

then use `func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` to handle touch event

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ){
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchNode = atPoint(location)

        if !((touchNode.name) != nil) { return }

        switch touchNode.name! {
            case "Play" :
                //your logic here!!
                let trialScene = TrialScene(size: self.size)
                self.view! .presentScene(trialScene, transition: transition)
        ｝
    ｝

}
```